# Problema para hacer un update desde formulario

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo un problema para poder actualizar registros desde un formulario de php. Tengo varios formularios, código que repito mucho, y que me están funcionando en todos menos este, llevo dos días buscando una solución y no veo solución.

Por una parte no puedo actualizar, a pesar que al pulsar el botón Editar redirige a la página.

En el registro de la base de datos no muestra ningún cambio.

```
include("../conn/connection.php");
 
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
 
    # retrieve information from form.
 
    $entidad = $_POST['entidad'];
    $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
    $vivienda = $_POST['vivienda'];
    $poliza = $_POST['poliza'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
    $fecha_contratacion = $_POST['fecha_contratacion'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $expirado = (isset($_POST['expirado'])) ? 1 : 0;
 
    $query = "UPDATE seguros SET entidad='$entidad',tipo='$tipo',vivienda='$vivienda',poliza='$poliza',telefono='$telefono',fecha_contratacion = '$fecha_contratacion',cantidad='$cantidad',descripcion ='$descripcion',expirado = $expirado WHERE id = '".$id."'";
 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
 
    if ($result){
        header("location:seguros.php");
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }
}
 
?>
```

Agradecería si alguien me pudiese ayudar a encontrar el fallo.

Expongo la tabla de mysql y luego el php.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

**el show create table seguros;**

```
    CREATE TABLE `seguros` (
 `id` smallint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `entidad` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `tipo` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `vivienda` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `poliza` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `telefono` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `fecha_contratacion` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
 `cantidad` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,`introducir el código aquí`
 `descripcion` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `expirado` tinyint(3) DEFAULT 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_mysql500_ci
```

**El archivo php entero**

````
  <?php
require('../session/cookie.php');
ob_start();
session_start();
if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
    header("location:../../index.php");
}
 
?>
 
<script language="JavaScript">
//Evitar botón derecho & Cntrl - Shift + I,C,J, o Cntrl U
document.oncontextmenu = function(){return false}
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if(event.keyCode == 123) {
        return false;
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'I'.charCodeAt(0)) {
        return false;
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'C'.charCodeAt(0)) {
        return false;
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'J'.charCodeAt(0)) {
        return false;
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'U'.charCodeAt(0)) {
        return false;
    }
}
 
function pregunta(){
    if (confirm('¿Estas seguro de guardar este registro?')){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
 
function countChars(obj){
    var maxLength = 255;
    var strLength = obj.value.length;
    var charRemain = (maxLength - strLength);
 
    if(charRemain <= 5){
        document.getElementById("charNum").innerHTML = '<span style="color: red;">Faltan menos de '+charRemain+' caracteres</span>';
    }else{
        document.getElementById("charNum").innerHTML = '<span style="color: green;">Faltan '+charRemain+' caracteres</span>';
    }
}
 
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Actualización de registro seguros</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="guardar_seguros" content="Seguros">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/seguros.css">
 
 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="base">
 
        <div id="log_out">
            <a id="log_out_button" href="../session/logout.php">Cerrar Sesión</a>
        </div>
        <div id="pic">
            <picture>
                <img id="imagen" src="../../images/recibos.png" alt="Recibos">
            </picture>
        </div>
 
        <div>
            <h1>Actualización registro de inquilinos</h1>
            <div id="menu"><a class="button" href="seguros.php">Inicio</a>-<a class="button" href="search.php">Busqueda</a></div>
        </div>
 
    <?php
      require("../conn/connection.php");
 
    if(isset($_GET['GetID'])){
        $id = $_GET['GetID'];
 
        $query="Select * from seguros where id = '".$id ."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
 
    ?>
        <div>
            <center>
                <form action="seguros.php" name="formulario" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <br>
 
                    Entidad:    <input type="text" name="entidad" placeholder="entidad" value="<?php echo $row['entidad']; ?>" size="50" maxlength="50" required /><br><br>
 
                    Tipo: <select name="tipo">
                                <option value="<?php echo $row['tipo']; ?>"><?php echo $row['tipo']; ?></option>
                                <option value="Hogar">Hogar</option>
                                <option value="Alquiler">Alquiler</option>
                                <option value="Hogar+Alquiler">Hogar+Alquiler</option>
                                <option value="Coche">Coche</option>
                            </select>
                    Vivienda: <select name="vivienda">
                                <option value="<?php echo $row['vivienda']; ?>"><?php echo $row['vivienda']; ?></option>
                                <option value="Calle Avila">Calle Avila</option>
                                <option value="Pablo Casals">Calle Pablo Casals</option>
                                <option value="Lago Tiberiades">Calle Lago Tiberiades</option>
                                <option value="Calle Mesones">Calle Mesones</option>
                            </select>
                    Poliza:    <input type="text" name="poliza" placeholder="poliza" value="<?php echo $row['poliza']; ?>"size="20" maxlength="20" /><br><br>
                    Telefono:    <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="telefono" value="<?php echo $row['telefono']; ?>"size="15" maxlength="15" /><br><br>
                    Cantidad:   <input type="number" name="cantidad" value="<?php echo $row['cantidad']; ?>" step=".01" required /><br><br>
                    Fecha de contratación:  <input type="date" name="fecha_contratacion" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['fecha_contratacion'])); ?>"/><br><br>
                    Expirado: <input type="checkbox" name="expirado" <?= $row['expirado']=='1'?"checked='checked'" : "" ?> /><br><br>
                    Descripción: <textarea name="descripcion" cols="40" rows="5"  > <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['descripcion']) ?></textarea><br><br>
                            <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return pregunta()" value="Editar" />
                            <input class="button" type="reset">
                        </form>
                    </center>
                </div>
                <!--FIN DIV BASE-->
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
 
    <?php }
} ?>
 
 
        <?php
        include("../conn/connection.php");
 
        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
 
            # retrieve information from form.
 
            $entidad = $_POST['entidad'];
            $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
            $vivienda = $_POST['vivienda'];
            $poliza = $_POST['poliza'];
            $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
            $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
            $fecha_contratacion = $_POST['fecha_contratacion'];
            $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
            $expirado = (isset($_POST['expirado'])) ? 1 : 0;
 
            $query = "UPDATE seguros SET entidad='$entidad',tipo='$tipo',vivienda='$vivienda',poliza='$poliza',telefono='$telefono',fecha_contratacion = '$fecha_contratacion',cantidad='$cantidad',descripcion ='$descripcion',expirado = $expirado WHERE id = '".$id."'";
 
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
 
            if ($result){
                header("location:seguros.php");
            }else{
                echo "Error";
            }
        }
 
    ?>
        <?php
        /* Cerrar la conexión */
        mysqli_close($conn);
        ob_end_flush();
        ?>```
````

Answer (score 1):

Existen varios puntos por comentar de tu código.

1. El *enctype* que usas no es el indicado, puesto que en tu formulario no parece que tengas algún `input` de tipo `file`.

Por tanto debes cambiar esto:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

A esto:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

**Sin embargo** respecto de este último punto también será el valor tomado *por default* para el atributo `enctype` en caso de que no esté declarado<sup>1</sup>

2. Ahora **con fines de depuración nadamás** y ya que estás trabajando con *mysqli* considero que deberías **activar temporalmente** las funciones internas de notificación<sup>2</sup> de esta manera en tu archivo de conexión:

   ```
    $notificacionesError = new mysqli_driver();
    $notificacionesError->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL;
   ```

De este modo tu código será capaz de notificarte de una forma mas exacta el posible error que esté ocurriendo al momento de intentar procesar tu consulta.

3. Cuando realizas una consulta que se compone de valores dinámicos (*en este caso enviados por el usuario desde un formulario*), lo recomendado es que lo hagas mediante sentencias preparadas<sup>3</sup>

   ```
    $id = $_GET['GetID'];

    /*
        Resto de tu código
    */


    $tipo     = $_POST['tipo'];
    $poliza   = $_POST['poliza'];
    $entidad  = $_POST['entidad'];
    $vivienda = $_POST['vivienda'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
    $expirado = (isset($_POST['expirado'])) ? 1 : 0;
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $fecha_contratacion = $_POST['fecha_contratacion'];

    try {
        $query = $conn->prepare("UPDATE seguros SET entidad = ?,
                                                tipo = ?,
                                                vivienda = ?,
                                                poliza= ?,
                                                telefono = ?,
                                                fecha_contratacion = ?
                                                cantidad = ?,
                                                descripcion = ?,
                                                expirado = ? 
                            WHERE id = ?");
        $query->bind_param("ssssssissi", $tipo, $poliza, $entidad, $vivienda, $telefono, $cantidad, $expirado, $descripcion, $fecha_contratacion, $id);
        $query->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
   ```

Respecto de este punto, considera leer a detalle el enlace que te dejo para que revises los valores que se pasan como *string* y que cada tipo de dato declarado empate con el que esperas en cada una de las variables.

Una vez que pases la etapa de las depuraciones, puedes considerar modificar tu código para establecer un mensaje de error personalizado en lugar de exponer directamente a los ojos de tus usuarios los avisos reales.

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup> [Atributo `enctype`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-enctype)
- <sup>2</sup> [mysqli_report](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php)
- <sup>3</sup> [Sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
- [Manejo de excepciones en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php)